# Hola, quiero agregar 600 nombres o mas a esta lista enlazada, pero no se como implementarlo y se me hace muy tedioso agregar uno por uno

Tags: java

Este es mi código, ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?

```java
 public static List<Canciones> getCanciones() {

 List<Canciones> col = new ArrayList<Canciones>();

 coll.add(new Canciones(5, "Bestia", 28));

 coll.add(new Canciones(1, "Adios", 19));

 coll.add(new Canciones(6, "Si nos dejan", 34));
 

 return coll;

 }

}
```

Comment: Si ya tienes todas las entradas en un documento, se puede usar Search and Replace en cualquier editor de texto para agregarle lo que falta del formato. El Notepad++ (por ejemplo) tiene opciones avanzadas, como saltos de línea, tabulaciones o incluso expresiones regulares.

Comment: Lo otro es que pongas cada linea en un archivo texto  y leas el archivo desde el programa. La linea debe tener cada dato  separado por una "," para que lo puedas luego  parsear.

Comment: Esos nombres que quieres agregar pueden ser al azar? Porque quizas existan librerias que generen nombres random.

Comment: si @AndresGardiol pueden ser generados al azar, que librerias serian?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la libreria [Java Faker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker)

La dependencia es:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Para usarlo podrías hacer lo siguiente.

```java
public static List<Canciones> getCanciones() {

 List<Canciones> coll = new ArrayList<Canciones>();

 for(int i=0; i < 600000; i++) {
   String name = new Faker().name().firstName();
   coll.add(new Canciones(5, name, 28));
 }

 return coll;
 }

}
```

En esta [demo](https://java-faker.herokuapp.com/) puedes ver los tipos de datos random que puedes generar en la libreria.